# How to get correct search terms from the user

Tags: javascript

I want to get correct search terms from the user even if the user gives incorrect spelling of the product and display products according to that. How can I do that and should I use AI for that?

Comment: This is very generic question. Google around, do some research and present some code here, that you have made an effort then people can help you. This way it is very much hard to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Bing spell check API.
Whenever someone types in the input field and event should be triggered which sends the request to the Bing API.
You can refer the documentation [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/spell-check/)